# Dockerfile error with "RUN pip install -r requirements.txt"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

when building python-flask webapp docker image. I am getting error with "pip install -r requirements.txt" command .

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 40b23f91d616
Processing /tmp/build/80754af9/bidict_1607541094382/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/bidict_1607541094382/work'

The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Source code with Dockerfile is available on github profile whose link is https://github.com/OCTO01032020-araju/Travel-WebApp-Flask.git

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7 
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
EXPOSE 5001 
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ] 
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Comment: I don't see any requirments.txt file in your git code, hence the pip install command failed.

Comment: neither the requirements.txt nor the Dockerfile are on github

Comment: Remove the `@ <file>` entries from your `requirements.txt` and replace them with version strings

Comment: You need to recreate your `requirements.txt` using `pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt`